# How can I align bootstrap's badge with AJAX inside the <li>

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently developing a website where a client user can request trucks on the website. **There is a notification when a client requests a truck**. It can only be seen by the admin. But **I cannot align the badge properly when I started to use AJAX for the real-time notification**. Because I have to put the badge (which already working with mysql) inside of the `<div>` tag.

---

Please take a look at the picture. **This is what I want to happen** [(Please click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNntk.png) *As you can see on the image, the badge right there is properly aligned* . But this is what I **have right now:** [(Please click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NhKg.png)
Your help will be highly appreciated. Here is my **code**:

**Script with AJAX:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>  

<script>
// <!--Realtime AJAX CODE-->

function ajax(){

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onreadystatechange = function(){

if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
            // (badge) id name of div
document.getElementById('badge').innerHTML = req.responseText; 
} 
}
req.open('GET','badge.php',true); //(badge.php) file to fetch requests
req.send();

}
setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);

// <!--End-->
</script>
```

**Bootstrap:**

```
<!-- start of NAV TABS HERE -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="index.php" title="Home page">Home</a>
    </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="trucks.php" 
      title="Trucks">Trucks</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="suppliers.php" 
      title="Suppliers">Suppliers</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="clients.php" title="Clients">Clients</a>
     </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="services.php" 
      title="Services">Services</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="accountspayables.php" title="Uploaded 
      Files">Uploaded Files</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="maintenance.php" 
      title="Maintenance">Maintenance</a></li>
  <!--  DROPDOWN start -->
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" 
      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      About us <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li role="presentation"><a href="contactus.php" title="Contact 
      us">Contact us</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="aboutus.php" title="About us">About 
      us</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <!-- END OF DROPDOWN -->

<!--  TRUCK REQUESTS START -->
 <li role="presentation"><a href="truckrequest.php" title="Truck request">
  <i class="fa fa-truck" style="font-size:21px;"></i>
    <!-- container for badge.php -->
    <div id="badge"></a></div>
 </li>
```

**badge.php:**

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "crb");
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM truckrequest WHERE STATUS=0";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  //fetch number of pending requests from table
?>
  <span class="badge"><?= $row["total"] ?></span></a>
<?php  }
?>
```

Comment: Did you check if `document.getElementById('badge').innerHTML = req.responseText; ` replaces/removes the closing a element `</a>` inside of `<div id="badge"></a></div>`?

Comment: You can't mix tags: `<div id="badge"></a></div>` you can't close the <a> tag here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use following CSS for this & update your HTML with following

```
<li role="presentation"><a href="truckrequest.php" title="Truck request"><i class="fa fa-truck" style="font-size:21px;"></i>
 <div id="badge"></div></a>
</li>

.nav-tabs li a i , .nav-tabs li a #badge {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: great actually works! the simplest & easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be as follows:
**Bootstrap:**

```
 <li role="presentation"><a href="truckrequest.php" title="Truck request">
  <i class="fa fa-truck" style="font-size:21px;"></i>
    <!-- container for badge.php -->
    <div id="badge"></div>
 </li>
```

**badge.php**

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "crb");
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM truckrequest WHERE STATUS=0";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  //fetch number of pending requests from table
?>
  <span class="badge"><?= $row["total"] ?></span>
<?php  }
?>
```

Remove the closing of anchor (`<a>`) tag from both. Might resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flexbox to align the items. You would however need to assign a separate class to `li`, because the role is used in different places.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

li[role="presentation"] {
  display: flex;
}

#badge {
margin-left: .5em;
background: red;
border: medium solid red;
border-radius: 100%;
width: 1em;
height: 1em;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<li role="presentation">
  <a href="truckrequest.php" title="Truck request">
    <i class="fa fa-truck" style="font-size:21px;"></i></a>
  <!-- container for badge.php -->
  <div id="badge">5</div>
</li>
```